# Algorithm - Check if there is a single type with the given word

Tags: algorithm, hashmap

Given a dictionary list and a input word, return true if the input word has a single typo with the same length as the vocabulary in the dictionary.

```
dictionary = ["apple", "testing", "computer"];
singleType(dictionary, "adple") // true
singleType(dictionary, "addle") // false
singleType(dictionary, "apple") // false
singleType(dictionary, "apples") // false
```

I proposed a solution that runs in linear time, if we ignore the pre-process time needed for the hashmap.

`O(k*26) => O(k)`, where `k = length of the input word`

My linear solution goes like, convert the dictionary list into a hash-map, where the key is the word and the value is a boolean, then loop through every character in the input word, and replace every character with 1 of the 26 alphabet and check if it maps to the hash-map.

But they say I could do better than `O(k*26)`, but how?

Comment: Maybe you could put all of `?pple, a?ple, ap?le, app?e, appl?` into the dict and look those up with just k lookups into the dict, but then the dict is considerably larger.

Comment: Wouldn't ur time complexity be multiplied by the length of dictionary size ? Because how do u know that it's the first string, u have to run k*26 for all the strings right ?

Comment: @tobias_k I think ur solution works, yeeeee!!! so tricky, wait

Comment: @tobias_k if the input word is "apple", it would return true, even though there is no typo. but I guess i could also add the word "apple" into the hashmap along with all the ?pple, a?ple, ap?le, app?e, appl?, and check if the word apple already exists or not.

Comment: You may split the dictionary into one dictionary per wordlength and only search in the one with matching length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the dictionary with all the variants of the word containing a single typo, but instead of the actual typo, you just put some "wildcard" character like `?` or `*` in that place. Then, you can check whether (a) the word is not in the set of correctly spelled words, and (b) replacing any of the letters in the word with the same wildcard symbol, the word can be found in the set of words having one typo.

Example in Python:

```py
>>> dictionary = ["apple", "testing", "computer"]
>>> wildcard = lambda w: [w[:i]+"?"+w[i+1:] for i in range(len(w))]
>>> onetypo = {x for w in dictionary for x in wildcard(w)}
>>> correct = {w for w in dictionary}
>>> word = "apxle"
>>> word not in correct and any(w in onetypo for w in wildcard(word))
True
```

This reduces the complexity of lookup to just O(k), i.e. still linear in the number of letters, but without the high constant factor. It does, however, greatly blow up the dictionary by a factor equal to the average number of letters in the words.

Answer (score 1):

For a single lookup, I would filter the dictionary by word length, and then iterate the words, counting the errors, and bail out of each word, as soon as the error count is > 1.

```
val dictionary = List ("affen", "ample", "apple", "appse", "ipple", "appl", "pple", "mapple", "apples")

@annotation.tailrec
def oneError (w1: String, w2:String, err: Int) : Boolean = w1.length match {
    case 0 => err == 1
    case _ => if (err > 1) false else {
        if (w1(0) == w2(0)) oneError (w1.substring (1),  w2.substring (1), err) else
        oneError (w1.substring (1),  w2.substring (1), err + 1)
    }
}

scala> dictionary.filter (_.length == 5).filter (s => oneError ("appxe", s, 0))
res5: List[String] = List(apple, appse)
```

For processing a longer text, I would preprocess the dictionary and split it into Maps (word.length -> List (words)).

For natural language, which is highly redundant, I would build a Set of unique words from the text, to lookup every word just once.

For a single word lookup, the worst case is n calls to the initial function, with n=max (dictionary.groupBy (w.length)).

Each word lookup (of words longer 1) will take at least 2 steps until failure, but most words, supposed no pathological input and dictionary, are only visited for 2 steps. From the remaining ones, most are excluded after 3 steps and so on.

Here is a version, which shows how deep it looks:

```
def oneError (word: String) : Array[String] = {

    @tailrec
    def oneError (w1: String, w2:String, steps: Int, err: Int) : Boolean = w1.length match {
        case 0 => {print (s"($steps) "); err == 1}
        case _ => if (err > 1) {print (s"$steps "); false } else {
            if (w1(0) == w2(0)) oneError (w1.substring (1),  w2.substring (1), steps +1, err) else
            oneError (w1.substring (1),  w2.substring (1), steps + 1, err + 1)
        }
    }

    val d = dict (word.length)
    println (s"Info: ${d.length} words of same length")
    d.filter (entry => oneError (word, entry, 0, 0))
}
```

Sample output, redacted:

```
scala> oneError ("fuck") 
Info: 3352 words of same length
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2  
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (4) 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 (4) (4) 3 3 3 3 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 (4) (4) 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 3 3 3 3 3 (4) 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
3 (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) (4) 3 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (4) (4) 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 (4) 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
2 2 2 2 2 2 (4) 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
res53: Array[String] = Array(Buck, Huck, Puck, buck, duck, funk, luck, muck, puck, suck, tuck, yuck)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the edit distance of 1 of your pattern with respect to the dictionary entry.  For example, an edit distance of 1 would result if the pattern is "adple" and your dictionary entry is "apple".  You have an additional constraint that the pattern is the same length as the dictionary entry, but this is easy to implement.

Comment: So, you suggest calculating the edit distance to every word in the dictionary? Do you think that this will be faster then OP's O(k*26)?